# OpenLayers SelectFeature and XY

Tags: javascript, events, maps, openlayers

I need to know exact point that was clicked on a feature. Using SelectFeature I can get info about which feature was clicked but there is no info about a location on the map.

Here is the code that creates a listner function:

```
select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
            [vectorLayer],
            {
                clickout: false, toggle: false,
                multiple: false, hover: false
            }
        );

osMap.addControl(select);
```

and here is my listener's definition:

```
vectorLayer.events.on({
            "featureselected": function(e) {
                 //here I need to get XY
                 //something like the code below 
                 //(it doesn't work but clearly explains what my idea is)           
                 var lonlat = osMap.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy);

            }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Niklas is right, I use something like that for popups :

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored(
  "popup", 
  map.getLonLatFromPixel(evt.xy),
  null,
  evt.text,
  null,
  false
);
```

You may use the MousePosition control if `evt` isn't available:

```
 map.getLonLatFromPixel(
   (map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition‌​")[0]).lastXy
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes - ok. The problem is that evt.xy is not available for such an event ("featureselected"):-(

Comment: You may use the MousePosition control, then use : map.getLonLatFromPixel((map.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition")[0]).lastXy)

Comment: Did you check out the link in my EDIT-section? It looks as though the xy could be included in featureselected as well.

Comment: Thanks for this (+1). The second option was best for me.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [getLonLatFromPixel](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getLonLatFromPixel) function on the Map object, together with the e.xy property.

EDIT:
Also, check [this setting](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Events-js.html#OpenLayers.Events.includeXY) on events. It looks as you could extract xy property from all types of mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

look at http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2089,
a patch is presented using this.handlers.feature.evt

```
new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([layer],{
    hover:true,
    eventListeners:{
      featurehighlighted:function(e){
        console.log(this.handlers.feature.evt.clientX-map.div.offsets[0]);
        console.log(this.handlers.feature.evt.clientY-map.div.offsets[1]);
    }
});
```